# Unable to pack my library back into a phar file

Tags: php, command-prompt, wampserver, phar

I have unpacked a phar file and now, I am trying to pack the phar file, but I keep getting an error. I am using wamp-server. I have looked at phpinfo() and modified the `php.ini` file. Here is the error I keep getting:

```
Executing phar files is disabled by php.ini setting 'phar.readonly'.
```

I have changed all my php.ini files to look like this:

```
[Phar]
; http://php.net/phar.readonly
;phar.readonly = Off
```

Even after all the changes are made, I still get the error. Is there something I do not understand? I have also modified all other .ini files in the php bins to make them look like this as well. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove semicolon before `phar.readonly` to assign `Off` value to it. It should look like this:-

```
[Phar]
; http://php.net/phar.readonly
phar.readonly = Off
```

***Note***:- If you want to change php.ini then first change its permission to write mode from read-only mode